# Change one recordtype into another record type from workflow

Tags: workflow, page-layout, record-type

I have 2 recordtype that name is `QualifyOpp_Type` and another one is `DiscoveryOpp_type`. When my stagename(this is picklist) is change from `Qualify` to `discovery` then change the record type to `DiscoveryOpp_type` and corresponding page layout from workflow. how to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a workflow rule with rule criteria as `formula evaluates to true`
Add this formula.

```
AND(
    ISCHANGED(stagename),
    ISPICKVAL(PRIORVALUE(stagename),"Qualify"),
    ISPICKVAL(stagename, "discovery")
)
```

Add a field update workflow action. Specify the fields.

```
Field to Update **Opportunity: Record Type**
Field Value **DiscoveryOpp_type**
```

Page layouts will be automatically change according to record types.